# use collide_point with a rotated widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to rotate a widget and then use the method collide_point to check if I'm touching the widget or not

The problem is that when I rotate the widget, the canvas (image) works fine, but the widget itself doesn't seems to rotate, so the check fails

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Game(Widget):
    pass

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.player.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("collide")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 300, 300
        self.game = Game()
        return self.game


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
<Game>:
    player: player
    Widget:
        id: player
        angle: 50
        size: 40, 200
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0.5,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                angle: self.angle
                origin: self.right, self.top
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
```

I expect to print collide when I touch in the image, but only print collide when I touch where the image was before the rotation

edited:

I must do someting like this? (it works, but there is not an easy way?)

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    top_center = Vector(self.player.center_x, self.player.top)
    touch_pos = Vector(*touch.pos)
    top2touch = touch_pos - top_center
    top2touch_rotate = top2touch.rotate(-self.player.angle)
    correct_touch = top_center + top2touch_rotate
    if self.player.collide_point(*correct_touch):
        print("collide")
```

Comment: You need to override on_touch_down to apply the same rotation to the touch before checking collision (or more accurately, to perform the inverse rotation).

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way of rotate the widget?

Comment: You can use a Scatter, but this comes with some additional baggage.